# Property 'router' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

```
class Details extends React.Component<Props & RouteComponentProps, {}> {
onClick {
this.props.router.push("/market");
}
}
```

I am getting error as **Property 'router' does not exist on type 'Readonly**. Can plz anyone help me with , how to use this.props.router. I am new to react router

Answer (score 1):

I think previous versions of react-router might have used the prop name `router`, but the current version does not.  They instead provide four separate props: `history`, `location`, `match`, and optional `staticContext`.  The `push` method that you are looking for is in the `history` prop.

```
class Details extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps, {}> {
    onClick = () => {
        this.props.history.push("/market");
    }
}
```